# How can I request a CSS attribut in HtmlUnit?

Tags: java, css, htmlunit

How can I request a CSS attribute like "display" from a HtmlElement in HtmlUnit? The attribute is not set directly to the else over CSS classes of parent nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the following:

```
   WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
   XHtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("…");
   HtmlElement div = page.getHtmlElementById("elem_container");
   WebWindow window = webClient.getCurrentWindow();
   Window jscript = (Window) window.getScriptObject();
   HTMLElement element = (HTMLElement) jscript.makeScriptableFor(div);
   ComputedCSSStyleDeclaration style = jscript.jsxFunction_getComputedStyle(element, null);
   System.out.println(style);
```